# Custom Keras metric, changing

Tags: tensorflow, computer-vision, keras, metrics

I am currently trying to create my own loss function for Keras (using Tensorflow backend). This is a simple categorical crossentropy but I am applying a factor on the 1st column to penalize more loss from the 1st class.
Yet I am new to Keras and I can't figure out how to translate my function (below) as I have to use symbolic expressions and it seems I can't go element-wise:

```
def custom_categorical_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred):
    y_pred = np.clip(y_pred, _EPSILON, 1.0-_EPSILON)
    out = np.zeros(y_true.shape).astype('float32')
    for i in range(0,y_true.shape[0]):
        for j in range (0,y_true.shape[1]):
            #penalize more all elements on class 1 so that loss takes its low proportion in the dataset into account
            if(j==0):
                out[i][j] = -(prop_database*(y_true[i][j] * np.log(y_pred[i][j]) + (1.0 - y_true[i][j]) * np.log(1.0 - y_pred[i][j])))
            else:
                out[i][j] = -(y_true[i][j] * np.log(y_pred[i][j]) + (1.0 - y_true[i][j]) * np.log(1.0 - y_pred[i][j]))
        out = np.mean(out.astype('float32'), axis=-1)
        return tf.convert_to_tensor(out,
                     dtype=tf.float32,
                     name='custom_loss')
```

Can someone help me?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `class_weight` in the `fit` method to penalize classes without creating functions:

```
weights = {
            0:2,
            1:1,
            2:1,
            3:1,
            ...
          }


model.compile(optimizer=chooseOne, loss='categorical_crossentropy')
model.fit(......., class_weight = weights)
```

This will make the first class be twice as important as the others.